# Preferred node for read on Availability Group in a multisite configuration

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

We are going to set up a multi (at least 2) site configuration, and we want to achieve both HA as well as a good resource usage.

The sites will be interconnected through a high speed, dedicated fiber network, so latency will generally be very low.

However we still prefer that each site uses the nearest secondary server for read intent data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but it isn't an out of the box configuration.  What you would need to do is setup a separate DNS named which points to all the secondary servers that you want to route requests to.  Then setup the read only routing to point to that secondary DNS name.  Then assuming that AD is setup correctly when people are redirected to that DNS name they'll always go to the local one.

Comment: I was thinking through this question and was thinking of heading there also Denny, but that requires a different connection string for each area. But more importantly it potentially takes other read only secondaries out of availability for them right? I was wondering if this would be a good enhancement request for Connect. What do you think Denny? Sort of adding some rules on secondary routing? Maybe a preferred order for clients? Or preferred order by subnet or even some rule looking at latency between machines?

Comment: Nope, you use a single DNS name and a single connection string, letting the read only routing handle the handoff to the DNS name.  Then the AD DNS servers direct you to the connect location based on which site you are sitting in.  I'll have to write up a blog post about it, because it's pretty complex to setup.

Comment: Hi Denny, this sounds like a good solution. I'm accepting the answer now because the question was it it was possible, but I hope you'll make that blog post anyway. If you do then please let me know.

Comment: Mrdenny, Did you ever write up this blog post? We are doing this and there is some confusion as to the DNS\AD configuration.